# UICollectionView with network data not showing cells until interacted with

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController loaded with *.xib. One element of this ViewController is a `UICollectionView`. I make an asynchronous network request in the ViewControllers `-viewDidLoad` and upon callback, i call `self.collectionView reloadData`. I also tried:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

Strangely, the collectionView does load cells but just not the ones that should be visible on screen without interaction. Once I scroll, the cells that scroll into view are displayed fine. When I scroll back to the start, the first cells appear too.

[image: Problem explained visually]

What am I missing?

My datasource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.listItems count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:9];
    if (!lbl) {
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
        [lbl setTag:9];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    }

    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.f green:1.f blue:(10*indexPath.row)/255.f alpha:1]];
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

And on callback all I do is set `self.listItems = myFetchedArray` and calling -reloadData on the collectionView...

Comment: What do you have in the datasource methods?  And how are you handling the data after the fetch completes?  Without these details this question is pointless.

Comment: @nhgrif, added. apologies.

Comment: I don't think it helps but after you called [self.collectionView reloadData];, could you also please try adding [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]; after it?

Comment: @opfeffer did you fix this? i'm having a very similar issue and i'm interested in your input :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the `collectionView` layout after the `reloadData`.

- **Objective-C**

`[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];`

- **Swift**

`collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`

> You can call this method at any time to update the layout information.
>   This method invalidates the layout of the collection view itself and
>   returns right away. Thus, you can call this method multiple times from
>   the same block of code without triggering multiple layout updates. The
>   actual layout update occurs during the next view layout update cycle.

[Apple - API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617728-invalidatelayout)